# interpreting Graphviz output for decision tree regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, graphviz, decision-tree

I'm curious what the `value` field is in the nodes of the decision tree produced by Graphviz when used for regression. I understand that this is the number of samples in each class that are separated by a split when using decision tree classification but I'm not sure what it means for regression.

My data has a 2 dimensional input and a 10 dimensional output. Here is an example of what a tree looks like for my regression problem:

[image]

produced using this code & visualized with webgraphviz

```python
# X = (n x 2)  Y = (n x 10)  X_test = (m x 2)

input_scaler = pickle.load(open("../input_scaler.sav","rb"))
reg = DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion = 'mse', max_depth = 2)
reg.fit(X,Y)
pred = reg.predict(X_test)
with open("classifier.txt", "w") as f:
    f = tree.export_graphviz(reg, out_file=f)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What a regression tree actually returns as output is the *mean value* of the dependent variable (here Y) of the training samples that end up in the respective terminal nodes (leaves); these mean values are shown as lists named `value` in the picture, which are all of length 10 here, since your Y is 10-dimensional.

In other words, and using the leftmost terminal node (leaf) of your tree as an example:

- The leaf consists of the 42 samples for which `X[0] <= 0.675` and `X[1] <= 0.5`
- The mean value of your 10-dimensional output for these 42 samples is given in the `value` list of this leave, which is of length 10 indeed, i.e. the mean of `Y[0]` is `-152007.382`, the mean of `Y[1]` is `-206040.675` etc and the mean of `Y[9]` is `3211.487`.

You can confirm that this is the case by predicting some samples (from your training or test set - it doesn't matter) and checking that your 10-dimensional result is one of the 4 `value` lists depicted in the terminal leaves above.

Additionally, you can confirm that, for each element in `value`, the weighted averages of the children nodes are equal to the respective element of the parent node. Again, using the first element of your 2 leftmost terminal nodes (leaves), we get:

```python
(-42*152007.382 - 56*199028.147)/98
# -178876.39057142858
```

i.e. the `value[0]` element of their parent node (the leftmost node in the intermediate level). One more example, this time for the first `value` elements of your 2 intermediate nodes:

```python
(-98*178876.391 + 42*417378.245)/140
# -0.00020000000617333822
```

which again agrees with the `-0.0` first `value` element of your root node.

Judging from the `value` list of your root node, it seems that the mean values of all elements of your 10-dimensional Y are almost zero, which you can (and should) verify manually, as a final confirmation.

---

So, to wrap-up:

- The `value` list of each node contains the mean Y values for the training samples "belonging" to the respective node
- Additionally, for the terminal nodes (leaves), these lists are the actual outputs of the tree model (i.e. the output will always be one of these lists, depending on X)
- For the root node, the `value` list contains the mean Y values for the whole of your training dataset